# Should I use Basemaps or Layers to overlay two maps?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers, arcgis-online-basemaps

I'm trying to create a map that essentially has two maps on top of each other (chosen from many map choices) at the same time. One of maps will have an opacity slider. Should I be trying to use two basemaps? or should I be adding them as layers? What is the best way to go about doing this?

It should let there be an effect like this with the first map showing through the second.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you won't use ArcGIS Online basemaps, then don't add any map of the basemap type.
Add [Tiled map service](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_ags_tiled.html) and then add [Dynamic map service](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/map_dynamic.html). Add a slider to manage opacity of the top layer.

Generally, Esri refers to a basemap as to any reference map that is drawn underneath all other layers and is used for orientation. In terms of JS API, basemaps are Esri ArcGIS Online basemaps. I understand that it might be confusing though. I usually add an Esri basemap with this code: (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/map_simple.html). When I know that I won't use it (eg when having a custom cached AGS service - I just add tiled map service).

Comment: So what is the difference of Basemap and Tiledmap? Thanks for the answer by the way!

Comment: Updated my answer above, hope you get it!

Comment: Just so you know, that Tiled Map Service link doesn't work for me.